# trying to test that a field <> value with null values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a column that has null values as well as other values such as 'deactivated'.  I am trying to build a query that says "WHERE field <> 'deactivated" but it returns an empty result set.  From my research it seems to be because it can't compare to the null values.  But I haven't been able to figure out how to get around it.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it seems that you want nulls included in the result set, the correct condition would be

```
WHERE field <> 'deactivated' OR field IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for `NULL` specifically:

```
WHERE field <> 'deactivated' OR field IS NULL
```

FYI, you must use `IS NOT` and not a comparision operator because `NULL` doesn't equal anything. Even another `NULL`;

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using MySQL, you can use the ["equal to"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator:

```
WHERE NOT(field <=> 'deactivated')
```

In other, more SQL-standards compliant databases, you'd write

```
WHERE field IS DISTINCT FROM 'deactivated'
```

I have recently written a blog post on [the `DISTINCT predicate`](http://blog.jooq.org/2012/09/21/the-is-distinct-from-predicate/) and how it is supported in various databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's ["null-safe equal" operator <=>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

```
WHERE NOT field <=> 'deactivated'
```